# Query + Substitute

Tags: google-sheets

I need a multiple substitution for some columns.

Source: Sheet1
Dest: Sheet2

I'm proceeding like this:

In A1 of Sheet2

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:D)
```

Output to substitute

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | /1 | one | *1 |
| 2 | /4 | two | *2 |
| 3 | /7 | three | *3 |
| 4 | /9 | four | *4 |
| 5 | /7 | five | *5 |

In columns B and D I have to replace `/` and `*`

Here is what I need

**Final Result**

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | one | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | two | 2 |
| 3 | 7 | three | 3 |
| 4 | 9 | four | 4 |
| 5 | 7 | five | 5 |

This is the function I'm using without the desired result

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(Sheet1!A2:D), B1:B, "/", "" ), D1:D, "*", "" )
```

As result I have 1 in cell A1

Please give me some help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=arrayformula(query({Sheet1!A:D,if(Sheet1!B:B<>"",value(regexreplace({Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!D:D},"^\/|^\*",)),)},"select Col1,Col5,Col3,Col6",0))
```

Alternatively:

```
=arrayformula(query({Sheet1!A:D,value(regexreplace({Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!D:D},"^\/|^\*",))},"select Col1,Col5,Col3,Col6 where Col1 is not null",0))
```

If you have a header column, change `,0` to `,1` at the end.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I can add other columns? In short I used only 4 columns, but my range is up to BL, so I can do SELECT * ?

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(Sheet1!A2:D)&"", "^\/|^\*", ))
```

[image]